# How could have Jack manage his music?

Tags: yesterday

At the end of *Yesterday*

> Jack releases his music online instead of having it published.

How is that possible, since he had a contract with Debra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is not how is that *possible*, the question is how is that *legal*. Jack wasn't concerned with the legality of his actions. He doesn't care whether they'll sue him or not. He just wanted to release the songs so people could hear them, and focus on his relationship with Ellie, his other friends, and his family.

Comment: Yes, "legal" is what I had in mind (it is obviously possible technically). Since this was such a mountain of money, I do not really see how this could have just be met with a "meh" from the major. In real life he would probably have been in jail for the next 100 years.